# Are there any pro-EU parties left in the Icelandic parliament?

Tags: european-union, parties, iceland

The pro-EU [Bright Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bright_Future_(Iceland)) party failed to win any seats in the 2017 elections. Do any of the other parties with parliamentary representatives still favor Iceland joining the EU? I'm asking because during the [2015 controversy](https://grapevine.is/news/2015/03/13/foreign-minister-drops-iceland-eu-bid-doesnt-run-it-past-parliament-first/) of Iceland's withdrawal of their EU accession application it was mentioned that the cabinet at the time tried to pass the withdrawal measure by parliament, but was rejected, so the Icelandic government acted unilaterally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are currently eight parties in the Icelandic Parliament.

Five of these parties are Eurosceptic, and against accession to the EU:

- Independence Party (16 seats)
- Left-Green Movement (11 seats)
- Centre Party (9 seats)
- Progressive Party (8 seats)
- People's Party (2 seats)

Two of these parties are Pro-Europe and in favour of accession to the EU:

- Social Democratic Alliance (7 seats)
- Reform Party (4 seats)

The Pirate Party (6 seats) is neutral on the issue of accession to the EU, saying it should be decided by referendum.